# pydev eclipse, jython scripting , syspath

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, jython

PyDev has its own jython interpreter, inside `pydev.jython.VERSION`

that jython has its own python libraries i.e. `pydev.jython.VERSION/LIB/zipfile.py`

Now if I write a jython script for pydev-jython-scripting, it will load only its internal Lib  `pydev.jython.VERSION/LIB/`

How do I have this pydev-jython recognize `PYTHONPATH`, I tried appending to sys.path but there is some python version problem some invalid syntax

My system python installation has all the `.py` source, my pydev interpreter configuration has python interpreter setup and NOT jython and NOT ironpython

pydev-jython script does not recognize many of regular system python modules, why?

Answer (score 0):

The version that PyDev uses internally is Jython 2.1, so, you can't add newer libraries to that version unless they're compatible...

If you need to use a different version, you'd need to first update the version used inside PyDev itself (it wasn't updated so far because the current Jython size is too big -- PyDev has currently 7.5 MB and just the newer Jython jar is 10 MB -- with libs it goes to almost 16 MB, so making PyDev have 22 MB just for this upgrade is something I'm trying to avoid... now, I think there's probably too much bloat there in Jython, so, if that can be removed, it's something that may be worth revisiting...).

Comment: Who cares about the extra megabites :( I spend hours trying to get pep8 to run with Jython 2.1 that does not have set or finally or if else on one line ;((((

Comment: Well... the latest Jython jar has 40 MB now and there are many people (such as myself) which care about bloatedness (which is already a weak spot in Eclipse)... But it's already on my 'soon todo' list fixing the pull request that allows pep8 to be run externally :)